# load content of div with preloader without use cache

Tags: javascript, caching, preloader

I have a simple preloader :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function preloader(){
            document.getElementById("mioperspreloader").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("mioperswrapper").style.display = "block";
        }//preloader
        window.onload = preloader;
</script>
```

The second time that i reload my webpage the preloader load data from cache but i don't want!
can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say you have an image in the preloader and you want to prevent it from cache, then you have to change the url like:

```
    function preloader(){
        document.getElementById("mioperspreloader").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("mioperswrapper").style.display = "block";
        var img = document.querySelector("#mioperspreloader img.preloader");
        img.src = /images/preloader.png?__nocache__=" + new Date().valueOf();
    }
```

this way you are changing the url which is the key for cache.

But you might have more than one image in your preloader, or even ajax json responses, if you want to prevent all of them from cache, then do this for the urls.

you have said

> **the preloader load data from cache**

and loading data probably means you have ajax calls, then add a timestamp or any unique string you can come up with, as a nocache querystring to your ajax calls urls.

**jQuery solution**:
if you use wordpress or other frameworks those use jQuery, you can also do this, for your ajax calls:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

if you want to disable the cache, only for a specific phase, you have to run the same code with `cache: true`, to return to the normal mode:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
```

Comment: the problem is that the page in wich run  preloader is a wordpress page I have inserted script in functions.php of my wordpress theme I have not only images in page but all data ajax calls and other...

Comment: I think it means that script uses jQuery, if it is so then I just updated my answer, check it. let me know if it won't work.

Comment: you can also give me the website address, if it is not a local site, to check your page and your possible solutions.

Comment: I have added your jquery solution in my functions.php of wordpress theme in this mode: add_action( 'wp_footer', 'b50f_on_load_script' );

function b50f_on_load_script()
{
    // Not our page, do nothing
    if( !is_page( 'test' ) )
        return;

    ?><!-- jQuery Plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});

  </script>
  
    <?php           
}; and appear working

Comment: @grigione: if you want to disable it just for your preloader, chek my answer again.